# What should i be concerned about when powering a 10A load from 120VAC

Tags: power, power-factor-correction

I have something that needs to be powered 25 feet away from the wall(120V). The load requires 10A of current. I'm worried that line inductance would deform my input voltage and lead to a non ideal power factor. Are my concerns justified? Do i need to add a PF correction circuit near the input?

Comment: No, your concerns seem pretty invalid. How did you come to that conclusion? You could also be worried that a 25 feet (I'd need to convert that to metric units...) of cable attracts killer bees, at this point. I bet you have a valid reason why you're bringing this up, but your question doesn't tell us!

Comment: Just use an appropriately rated extension cord, or 14/3 power cord.  House wiring is much longer than 25 feet, with 15A and 20A rated circuits, and appliances, TVs, etc. run just fine.

Comment: Your electricity bill? Seriously: PF  depends on the type of load which you have told us nothing about.

Comment: @CrossRoads You are right about the house wiring thing. Thanks! I'm not very good at power.

Comment: @MarcusMüller it's a prime number of feet that attracts killer bees so 23 ft would be closest.

Comment: @Andyaka I'd agree, but you mustn't forget that in the case of sinusoidal deplanarization, the excessive thumbwheeling of the co-enfambulator might shorten the apparent cable constant!

Comment: What is the load, a motor?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Lol. I knew long wires carrying some current was an issue i just didn't know how long they needed to be. I'm an electronics guy. I work with mA. 10A is serious current to me lol. Since my application is inside, I think we'll be safe from the killer bees. Supercharged cockroaches though...I might be worried about that

Comment: How much wiring do you think is in the wall?

Answer (score 2):

25 feet is about 8 meters, which is about 8 microHenries. For a single wire.

But power cords have the return wire about 5mm away, so assume 10:1 reduction in inductance, or less than 1uH.

How much effect on your power?

Impedance (like resistance, but for changing currents) is computed as

Zl = 2 pi * frequency * inductance

Zl = 6.3 * 60 * 1e-6 = 377 e-6 = 0.000377 ohms

At 25 amps, you will have (v = I * Z) 25 * 0.000377, or
less than 0.01 volts, or about 0.01% reduction in voltage.

Answer (score 1):

> *I'm worried that line inductance would deform my input voltage and
>   lead to a non ideal power factor.*

Power factor irregularities relate to the load and not the feed wire (no matter how inductive it might be). A maximum inductance of 1 uH per metre for an individual wire is impossible to get on any feeder cable so at 25 feet (7.62 metres) you won't see anything anywhere near 7 uH and, of course this won't be a problem. Likely value: 1 uH for the whole cable.

> *Are my concerns justified?*

No.

Comment: Thanks for that! But doesn't the feed line line look like a load looking through the supply?

Comment: @PratikKunkolienkar, the actual supply is possibly several km away, looking at your house through kilometers of wiring. Adding 8 m at the end won't make any difference.

Comment: Agreed!! Thanks for answering my dumb question